# How do I get all checked columns in a table

Tags: jquery, html

I need to return number of cols selected and this is my code:

```js
getSelectedColumns: function() {

  var cols = [];
  $('tbody > tr > th input[type="checkbox"]:checked', table).each(function() {
    cols.push($(this).val());
  });

  return cols;
},
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-checkable" id="datatable_ajax">
  <thead>
    <tr role="row" class="heading">
      <th width="2%">
        <label class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-single mt-checkbox-outline">
     <input type="checkbox" class="group-checkable" data-set="#sample_2 .checkboxes" />
     <span></span>
     </label>
      </th>
      <th width="5%"><input type="checkbox" class="group-column-checkable" /> Closing Date </th>
```

Comment: the selector is not correct

Comment: You are selecting elements from th which is the child of tr, and tr is the child of tbody according to your selector statement. But when I looked at your incomplete html, I see, you have checkbox element in th which is the child of tr, and that tr is the child of thead.

For above incomplete html, following selector will run
$('thead > tr > th input[type="checkbox":checked]')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function getSelectedColumns() {
  var cols = [];
  $('thead tr th input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
    cols.push($(this).val());
  });

  return cols;
}

$("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", function() {
var test = getSelectedColumns();
  console.log(test);
  console.log("Count: " + test.length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-checkable" id="datatable_ajax">
  <thead>
    <tr role="row" class="heading">
      <th width="2%">
        <label class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-single mt-checkbox-outline">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="group-checkable" data-set="#sample_2 .checkboxes" value="100"/>
                    <span></span>
                </label>
      </th>
      <th width="5%"><input type="checkbox" class="group-column-checkable" value="200" /> Closing Date </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```